# Renormalization of a graph adjacency matrix

Tags: matrices, graph-theory, machine-learning, spectral-graph-theory, adjacency-matrix

I know for graph adjacency matrix $A$ and degree matrix $D$, the eigenvalues of $I+D^{-1/2}AD^{-1/2}$ are in $[0,2]$ and repeated use of this as a filter will cause the numerical insatbility. I also know that to overcome from this a renormalization technique is used to get the expression like $\tilde{D}^{-1/2}\tilde{A}\tilde{D}^{-1/2}$ where $\tilde{A}=A+I$ and $\tilde{D}=diag\left\{\Sigma_j \tilde{A}_{i,j} \right\}$. But what I don't understand is how these two expressions:$I+D^{-1/2}AD^{-1/2}$ and $\tilde{D}^{-1/2}\tilde{A}\tilde{D}^{-1/2}$ are equivalent.

Comment: Your definition of $\tilde{D}$ doesn't make sense. What is the summation over? Is this definition equivalent to $\tilde{D} = D + I$?

Comment: Thanks, now it is edited.

Comment: Yes you are wright it is $\tilde{D}=D+I$ but I don't know these two are equivalent.